# Bootstrap 4 If input type file has a value show Confirmation message before closing the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Hello guys How are you I'm working now on a project and i Want to create a simple trick.
I made a simple jQuery code but it still not working as I want.
The wole story said : **if input type file has a value show confirm message with yes or no before closing the modal**
so if the user want to leave the page and close the modal dialog it should show a confirmation message said if he is sure about closing the modal dialog....

**HTML CODE :**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_a" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_aLabel" aria-hidden="true"data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="uploadavatar">
        <input type="file" 
               class="custom-file-input" 
               id="ID12" 
               name="avatar"
               value=""
               hidden />
        <label role="button" class="btn" for="ID12">
            Upload Now
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modal_a', function (e) {
        $('#ID12').on('change', function(e){
            const FileLength = $(this)[0].files.length;
            if(FileLength > 0){
                const ConfirmMessage = confirm("Are you sure?");
                if(ConfirmMessage){
                    $("#ID12").val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's interesting with this input because when you add a file, there is no dom value. Hmmm

Comment: If you force value somehow onchange you might get the actual result you're after https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/x8q1brds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a little help from [terry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131895/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-modal-hiding-when-modal-hide-is-triggered-in-bootstrap).

Basically this code below check wether a file exists in the input...

If the file exists, a confirmation will be fired.

If the user cancels because they are not sure they want to submit their upload, then the modal will not close.

But if the upload file never existed in the upload input, then the modal will dismiss as normal :-)

```js
// launch the example modal
$('#test-modal').modal('show');

// check for changes on input and force value
$('#test-upload').on('change', function() {

  // force the value in the dom
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());

});

// lets run the confirm checks on hide
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#test-modal', function(e) {

  // if upload value is not empty/specified
  if ($('#test-upload').val() != '') {

    // confirm your sure about cancelling upload
    var uploadSure = confirm("You sure you want to cancel your upload?");

    // confirm checks
    if (!uploadSure) {

      // stop modal closing
      e.preventDefault();

    } else {

      // continue closing/hiding modal

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <form class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Upload Confirmation</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="test-upload">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal">
    Launch Modal
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```