# Is it possible to stop a modal hiding when modal hide is triggered in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap, when hitting the close button or the backdrop, is it possible to stop the modal hiding?

For example if I run a statement to check true or false. If false can I stop the modal hiding?

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#test-modal', function(e) {

  var confirm = confirm("Sure you wanna close this modal?");

  if (confirm == true) {

    // i'm sure, continue closing the modal

  } else {

    // halt closing this modal

  } 

});
```

There is a fiddle here ready to test...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/yc340rpd/

Comment: Yes its posible if you have a good amount of time. If a jquery animation close something with an effect over time you are able to reverse it or switch animation before it ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `e.preventDefault` in `hide.bs.modal` to prevent the modal from closing. Also, be aware that `confirm` is a window object, so you should probably pick a different variable name to avoid that.

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
$('#test-modal').modal('show');

$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#test-modal', function(e) {

  var shouldCloseModal = confirm("Sure you wanna close this modal?");

  if (!shouldCloseModal) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } 

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Test Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        Try close me and then stop me! If you can...

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```